# JHipster: how to import data from Excel file into my Entity in the database using Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

I'm new to JHipster and i'd like to add a button that allow me import Excel file to fill my entity in the database .
could anyone help me or give an idea

thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way will be to define a table e.g. *sourceFile* which should have at least one field of type **TextBlob**. JHipster will create for you all the ui for uploading a file in the table *sourceFile*. Then u can create a service which is using a lib like [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook) for reading and importing the uploaded excel file. In this way u can write some audits about when the file was upload and imported. Of course it's depends on your use case if this is feasible or not for you.